# What is the different between these two sentences

Tags: past-tense

I want to know what is the different between these two sentences;

- You did see her
- You saw her

Do this two words give the same meaning?

Comment: The former is more emphatic.

Comment: Hello, @user178049 I'ts more appreciated if you can give more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You saw her" is just a normal contruction of past tense, meaning you locate the situation in the past.

"You did see her" uses the same tense, but it's rather more emphatic. The emphasis is carried by the *emphatic-Do*; that is why it's so called.

This emphatic-do is commonly used when you are denying a previous statement. For example,

> A: I didn't see her.
>
> B: No, you *did* see her!

Answer (score -2):

They are two different ways of saying the same thing so yes they do give the same meaning but they are two different types of tenses. 'Did see' is past perfect tense and 'saw' is past simple tense.
Hope I was helpful!:)

Comment: The past perfect version should be "You had seen her"